# Unity Figure out the type of an object in scene

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, types

I am working with a scene that was created by someone else.

There are some objects in the scene that I need to dynamically reference from a script, but I can't figure out their type.

This might sound dumb, but I can't find any "properties", and the inspector doesn't seem to tell me the type of the selected object, just what components are in it.

So how can I find what Type it is, so that I can use

```
Component.FindObjectsByType<T>()
```

in scripts to get it (and a few others that are the same type)?

EDIT: I am using C#, but I am looking for a way, from the scene editor, to find the type of a specific object, so that I can use that type later when I'm writing scripts. For example, some objects are Terrains, Sprites, Cubes, etc.

Comment: Your question is confusing. You want to reference a script from another script so that you can call functions or access properties from that script? You may want to tag the language you are using. C# or Unityscript/Javascript.

Comment: All objects you're selecting are of type GameObject. A Terrain is a GameObject with a Terrain Component. If you do "myterrain = FindObjectsByType<Terrain>();", you will get a reference to the instance of that component. If I'm not mistaken.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All objects in the scene are of type GameObject. What you are searching for are components. You can learn about components and how they work here in [documentation.](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Components.html)

If you want to access methods and variables of a component, you can do it multiple ways.

If you want to access a component of a GameObject, you can do it like this:

```
SpriteRenderer sprite = gameObject.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
```

If you want to get all components of some type in the scene, you can do it like this:

```
CharacterController[] controller = FindObjectsOfType<CharacterController>();
```

Comment: What if I don't know types of components of GameObject in runtime and want to retrieve all of them programmatically.
Is that possible?
Also as I am new to unity, so I don't know exact component name even for Button because there are at least 2 standart buttons (one in "legacy" block).
Is there a way how to retrieve type of scene element from Inspector?